# Google App Script e.user results in question mark

Tags: google-apps-script

I've recently encountered an issue using e.user within Google App Script. The resulting output is suddenly always a '?' and no longer the logged in user. No code was changed and it worked without fail for months. I can't tell if this could be an issue related to my companies domain or if it is related to any changes to the google apps platform.

My google spreadsheet workflow includes a script triggered by an OnEdit Event. The idea is that a user sets a status column for requests that come in and a separate cell is populated with that users email address to denote who changed the status.

Here is the part of my code that is no longer working as it should.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCol = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn()
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getValue()
      if (activeCol = 7) {
        var nextColumnCell = ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 1);
        var requesterCell = ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -5).getValue().toString();
        if (activeCell == 'Complete' || activeCell == 'In-Progress' || activeCell == 'Duplicate Request' ) {
        Logger.log(e.user);
          nextColumnCell.setValue(e.user);
          nextColumnCell.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date().toString());
        } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In September there was a change in the platform that may be affecting you:

> **[September 3, 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/?hl=en#september_2013)**
>
> - ...
> - Removed the ability to get the user's email address in [simple onEdit()
>   triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=en#simple-triggers). Because simple triggers don't request user authentication,
>   this change was important to protect the identity of collaborators who
>   hadn't explicity granted permission for the script to collect their
>   email address.